# Guzzle HTTP request transforms from POST to GET

Tags: php, guzzle

I have this very weird thing going on when trying to make post to an external API, I try to make a POST request to the URL but Guzzle make a GET request instead (which is a legal action on this API but returns something different).

Here is the code:

```
$request = $this->client->createRequest('POST', 'sessions', [
  'json' => [
    'agent_id' => $agentId,
    'url' => $url
  ],
  'query' => [
    'api_key' => $this->apiKey
  ]
]);

echo $request->getMethod(); // comes out as POST
$response = $this->client->send($request);
echo $request->getMethod(); // suddenly becomes GET
```

Same thing happens when I use `$this-client->post(…)`

I really have no idea what to do next.

Comment: What do you get when the debug option is true?  Is the client actually sending a POST or a GET?

Comment: Turns out my body was not valid and I was getting redirected. Thanks for the debug suggestion, I didn't knew that was available.

Answer (score 11):

I run into the same problem.
the reason is that Guzzle Changes the Request-Method to 'GET' when there is a location Redirect with code 301 or 302.
I found the 'Problem-Code' in the [RedirectMiddleware.php](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/a88a06be44e3763213a3ecda2fab9bfbcb8cb356/src/RedirectMiddleware.php#L167).

But when you see the if-condition you can disable this behavior by adding `'allow_redirects'=>['strict'=>true]` to your options.
After finding this option, I discovered that the option is listed in the [Guzzle Options Documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#allow-redirects)

So yust rewrite your createRequest like this:

```
$request = $this->client->createRequest('POST', 'sessions', [
  'json' => [
    'agent_id' => $agentId,
    'url' => $url
  ],
  'query' => [
    'api_key' => $this->apiKey
  ],
  'allow_redirects'=> ['strict'=>true]
]);
```

And it should stay Method `POST` after the redirect.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably getting a 3xx status code so that that the `Redirect` subscriber kicks in (redirect is enabled by default). From the [docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#redirects):

> [...] Pass an associative array containing the ‘max’ key to specify
>   the maximum number of redirects and optionally provide a ‘strict’ key
>   value to specify whether or not to use strict RFC compliant redirects
>   (**meaning redirect POST requests with POST requests vs. doing what
>   most browsers do which is redirect POST requests with GET requests**).

//edit Just saw you kinda answered that yourself in the [question comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470839/guzzle-http-request-transforms-from-post-to-get/29588578#comment47134963_29470839) - still leaving this answer online as it provides some context.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the key 'query' to 'body'.

Answer (score 0):

Please switch `query` to `form_params`. In Guzzle 6 it works.